# How to fix the error (TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object '#<QueryCursor>')

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, fetch, typeerror

I am sending my data to MongoDB via Mongoose. Now, during the fetch of API route for it, an error is thrown.

Code

```js
const addChoice = async (e) => {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        const res = await fetch("/api/sendChoice", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                choiceSeq: choice,
                checkSubmit: true,
            }),
        });
        console.log(res);
        router.push("/home");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

The error is happening at `const res = await fetch("/api/sendChoice" ,{`

In terminal server the error

> error - TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object
> '#<QueryCursor>'

In the inspect element the error is as
[image: this]

I can't find anything related to fix this issue, I don't even understand what the error means to try to resolve it myself.

Some other related code from my project:

api/sendChoice

```js
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client";
import dbConnect from "../../helpers/dbConnect";
import Choice from "../../models/Choice";

export default async function sendChoice(req, res) {
    try {
        const session = await getSession({ req });
        await dbConnect();
        if (!session) {
            res.status(401).send("You are not signed in");
            return;
        }
        if (req.method === "POST") {
            console.log(req.body);
            const { choiceSeq, checkSubmit } = req.body;
            console.log(choiceSeq, checkSubmit);
            const userId = session.user.id;
            const nameP = session.user.name;
            const choice = new Choice({
                user: userId,
                name: nameP,
                choiceSeq,
                checkSubmit,
            });
            await choice.save();
            res.status(200).send("Choice saved");
        } else {
            res.status(400).send("Bad request");
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The MongoDB schema

```js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const ChoiceSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    choiceSeq: {
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    },
    checkSubmit: {
        type: Boolean,
    }
});

mongoose.models = {};

export default mongoose.model('Choice', ChoiceSchema);
```

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, the error is a 500 Internal Server Error. If you created the server for which this call is made, have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @tomerpacific The server works fine i think because the google auth data is getting saved.

Comment: @tomerpacific [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11377) it just happened, thats why my app crashed. if you know any alternative please tell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079556/does-anyone-know-nay-fix-for-this-error-typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-p

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the latest update to version 17.5.0 is the one causing this error. You must reinstall node js to version 16.14.0 LTS. You should always work with LTS versions

Comment: Hey, so how do I keep my version of nodejs when ubuntu wants to automatically update for me, and isn't sticking with the LTS version?

Comment: @Bennington You can try using nvm instead of installing Node directly - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 9):

This issue occured recently and apparently its happening with latest version of node.

[issue link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11377)

So you can change the version of node to older version and it will be fixed. I am using node version v14.19.0

Answer (score 7):

if you are using Docker then, giving a version will solve the problem.

before:

```
FROM node:alpine
```

now

```
FROM node:16.5.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=prod
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of Node.JS is what is causing this issue. In your package.json, make sure to set your engine to`"engines": { "node": ">=0.12 < 17.5.0" }` and you should be fine.

Also if you are using docker for deployment, make sure to change the version number in your dockerfile to be less that 17.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Solution which worked well for me:)

Step 01: Open your terminal and copy paste below command.

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | zsh

Wait patiently until its done.

Step 02: sudo vim ./zshrc

Step 03: Press I for Insert Mode and copy paste below command. Must be same in three lines.

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

then press ESC key :wq (write and quite).

Step 04: brew install nvm

step 05: nvm install node (which will download latest version node)

step 06: nvm ls-remote (which make all the version available)

step 07: nvm install 14 (An Example)

step 08: nvm use 14 (this make it as default version)

source: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to v17.6.0. It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In My case eslint 8.9.0 was the culprit. Rollback fixed it.