# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object '#<QueryCursor>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm getting this error when I tried to host my logging bot on `pterodactyl`, but it works completely fine when I host it on my localhost or [replit](https://replit.com).

I'm using version 5.11.14 and it used to work fine.

```js
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);
const { db_pass } = require(`../../data/config.json`)

module.exports = {
  init: () => {
    const dbOptions = {
      useNewURLParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      autoIndex: false,
      poolSize: 5,
      connectTimeoutMS: 10000,
      family: 4
    }

    mongoose.connect(`mmy connection`, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

    mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
      console.log("Connected to the database!")
    })

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
      console.log("Disconnected from the database!")
    })

    mongoose.connection.on('err', (err) => {
      console.log("Error on the db " + err)
    })

  }
}
```

The error:
[image: Terminal]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know nay fix for this error (TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object '#<QueryCursor>')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073107/does-anyone-know-nay-fix-for-this-error-typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-p)